# How do I include Underscore in Typescript so that it can be used in CoffeeScript

Tags: webpack

I have the following structure

```
src
  main
    coffee
      app.coffee
    typescript
      polyfills.ts
      deps.ts
```

Deps is where I am loading all of my dependencies. However, when I try `import "underscore"`, the coffeescript cannot see it.

According to this [link](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#provideplugin), it looks like I should be handling this like the following...

```
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        _: 'underscore'
    })
```

The problem is when I hit a debug point inside the coffeescript. I try `$`, `jQuery`, and `_`. `$` seems to work but the other 2

```
> $
Object {jStorage: Object}
> jQuery
VM28129:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(…)(anonymous function) @ VM28129:1(anonymous function) @ app.js:342__webpack_require__ @ polyfills.js:51(anonymous function) @ app.js:8__webpack_require__ @ polyfills.js:51webpackJsonpCallback @ polyfills.js:22(anonymous function) @ app.js:1
>_
VM28130:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined(…)
```

What am I missing here?

*Update*

Seems to be a Chrome issue? If I try on Firefox I see...

```
$
function jQuery(selector, context)
jQuery
function jQuery(selector, context)
_
function _(obj)
```

Maybe related to https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2145?

Answer (score 0):

`window['_'] = require("underscore");`

This works.